Traefik - Can't connect to dashboard by custom link
I’m setting up a CI/CD pipeline using GitLab CI/CD along with Traefik as a reverse proxy. The pipeline works fine, and the services are deployed successfully. However, I'm facing an issue with accessing the Traefik dashboard through the configured subdomain (traefik.dev.domen.com).
I want to access the Traefik dashboard via http(s)://traefik.dev.domen.com using Let's Encrypt for SSL certificates.
Current Setup:
In my DNS records, I’ve added:
*.dev.domen.com
dev.domen.com
docker-compose.yml:
example


services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v3.2.0
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
      - 8080:8080
    deploy:
      labels:
        - traefik.enable=true

        - traefik.http.middlewares.auth.basicauth.users=admin:$pssw

        - traefik.http.middlewares.https-redirect.redirectscheme.scheme=https
        - traefik.http.middlewares.https-redirect.redirectscheme.permanent=true

        - traefik.http.routers.traefik-public-http.rule=Host(`traefik.dev.domen.com`)
        - traefik.http.routers.traefik-public-http.entrypoints=http
        - traefik.http.routers.traefik-public-http.middlewares=https-redirect

        - traefik.http.routers.traefik-public-https.rule=Host(`traefik.dev.domen.com`)
        - traefik.http.routers.traefik-public-https.entrypoints=https
        - traefik.http.routers.traefik-public-https.tls=true
        - traefik.http.routers.traefik-public-https.service=api@internal
        - traefik.http.routers.traefik-public-https.tls.certresolver=le
        - traefik.http.routers.traefik-public-https.middlewares=auth

        - traefik.http.services.traefik-public.loadbalancer.server.port=8080
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - traefik-public-certificates:/certificates
    command:
      - --log.level=DEBUG

      - --api.dashboard=true
      - --api.insecure=true

      - --providers.docker
      - --providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false
#      - --providers.docker.swarmmode
      - --providers.swarm=true
      - --entrypoints.http.address=:80
      - --entrypoints.https.address=:443

      - --certificatesresolvers.le.acme.email=ov@xd.com
      - --certificatesresolvers.le.acme.storage=/certificates/acme.json
      - --certificatesresolvers.le.acme.tlschallenge=true

      - --accesslog
      - --log
      - --api
    networks:
      - internal

volumes:
  traefik-public-certificates:

networks:
  internal:
    name: internal



What Works:
The CI/CD pipeline deploys services successfully.
What Doesn’t Work:
Visiting https://traefik.dev.domen.com results in an error (e.g., "Page not found" or a timeout).
The Traefik dashboard is not accessible through the subdomain.

Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your question and add the relevant parts of your code as text instead of an image. Otherwise this question is unlikely to get answers.
